# Code isnt working properly, unless i extend class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Im practicing polymorphism and inheritance, and i made a class (Animals) that sets the name of the animal, then i made a subclass (Cat) that sets the sound it makes, favourite toy.. all that. i tried testing it in a seperate class (Test) to print out "Cat likes to Moew, its favourite toy is Yarn" but its not working unless i extend Cat in the test class.

Heres my code.

Animals.java

```
public class Animals {

protected static String name;

public Animals() {

}

public Animals(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String setName(String newName) {
    return this.name = newName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name = name;
}

public static void animMove() {
    System.out.println(name + " likes to walk");
}

}
```

Cat.java

```
public class Cat extends Animals {

public static String sound;
public static String favToy;

public String getSound(String sound) {
    return this.sound = sound;
}

public String getToy(String favToy) {
    return this.favToy = favToy;
}

public Cat() {

}

public Cat(String name, String sound, String favToy) {
    super(name);
    this.sound = sound;
    this.favToy = favToy;
}

}
```

test.java

```
public class test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animals anim = new Animals();

    Cat cat = new Cat("Cat", "moew", "Yarn ball");
    System.out.println(anim.getName() + " Likes to " + cat.getSound(sound) 
    + ", its favourite toy is a " + cat.getToy(favToy));


}

}
```

All works fine if i extend Cat to the test class, but when i dont, none of the variables like sound and favToy work. how would i do this without extending anything to the test class

Comment: Why are you using parameters in getters of Cat class. Getters are supposed to return the value corresponding to that object, which does not need any parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make the name variable static. This would mean that it belongs to the class and not an `Animal` object, meaning there will only ever be one `Animal.name` in the class. Your `Cat.sound`, `Cat.favoriteToy` variables are also static, which will mean all cats will have the same sound and same favorite toy (I guess this is acceptable, but then dont assign this in a constructor).

Setters don't need to have a return value (you are only changing some variable). For example:

```
public void setName(String newName) {
   this.name = newName;
}
```

Getters do not need any parameters. You already know what to return, no need for a parameter. For example:

```
public String getSound() {
   return this.sound;
}
```

Also, your `Animals` should be `Animal`, as this class represents a single animal.

If you create a `Cat` object, this will automatically be `Animal` as well (its inherited), so no need to create both, as you do in your main method

```
Cat myCat = new Cat("Purr","meow","ball"); //create cat
System.out.println(myCat.getName());
```

variables are static so all cats will have this name, sound and fav toy now...

Comment: Thank you, had a bunch of random stuff in there it looks like, this helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried to do something like

1)

```
public class Animal {

    protected String name;

    public String animMove() {
        return new String(this.name + " likes to walk");
    }

}
```

2)

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

    public String sound;
    public String favToy;

    public Cat(String name, String sound, String favToy) {
        super(name);
        this.sound = sound;
        this.favToy = favToy;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return super.name;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return this.sound;
    }

    public String getToy() {
        return this.favToy;
    }

}
```

3)

```
public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal anim = new Cat("Cat", "moew", "Yarn ball");

        System.out.println(anim.getName() + " Likes to " + anim.getSound(sound) + ", its favourite toy is a " + anim.getToy(favToy) + " " + anim.animMove());

    }

}
```